# Não foi possível setar a variável com fetch_object

Tags: php, variáveis

Estou tentando fazer uma consulta simples porém, apesar do PHPMyAdmin realizar a consulta, quando vou executar o código o Apache retorna a mensagem:

Notice: Undefined variable: rprd in D:\xampp\htdocs\final\views\premorc.php on line 2723

Meu código está assim:

```
$data   = date("d-m-Y");
$partes = explode("-", $data);
$ano    = $partes[2];
$lj    = $_GET['emp'];
$linha  = $_GET['ans'];
$modal  = $_GET['modal'];

$periodo = "$ano%";

$sql = "SELECT 
  sjy_vendas.tipo, 
  Sum(sjy_vendas.qt) AS qt, 
  Sum(sjy_vendas.qtv) AS qtv, 
  Sum(sjy_vendas.rprd) AS rprd, 
  Sum(sjy_vendas.rsrv) AS rsrv, 
  Sum(sjy_vendas.tprd) AS tprd, 
  Sum(sjy_vendas.tsrv) AS tsrv, 
  Sum(sjy_vendas.vlr_compra) AS vlr_compra
  FROM sjy_vendas
  WHERE sjy_vendas.empresa = $lj 
  AND sjy_vendas.tipo = $linha
  AND sjy_vendas.dt_nf LIKE '$periodo'
  GROUP BY sjy_vendas.tipo";

$resultado = $MySQLi->query($sql) OR trigger_error($MySQLi->error, E_USER_ERROR);
while ($dados = $resultado->fetch_object()) {


$qtv    = $dados["qtv"];
$rprd   = $dados["rprd"];
}

if($modal == "X"){
    $anterior = $qtv;
} else if($modal = "F"){
    $anterior = $rprd; // Essa é a linha 2723
}
```

Comment: Quer dizer que sua consulta não retornou nada (não entrou no while) ou talvez esse if/else deveria estar dentro do while.

Comment: Você ta buscando um objeto, e acessando com uma array, não vai buscar mesmo, ve se alterar onde está "$dados['qtv']" por "$dados->qtv" ja não resolve

Comment: Rray, obrigado pela resposta. Para definir a variável eu só preciso do código que já está descrito.

Comment: AnthraxisBR obrigado pela resposta, mas está dando o mesmo erro. Já tentei com fetch_array e dá o mesmo erro. Esse código está funcionando em outra página (com outra consulta é claro), mas aqui está dando erro.

Comment: Coloca $dados = $resultado->fetch_object() fora do while, e coloca var_dump($dados), pra ver se a consulta está sendo feita

Comment: Valeu @AnthraxisBR, era isso mesmo. Eu tava setando um objeto com uma array. Agora tá funcionando. Obrigado.

Comment: Mas quando eu copiei e colei da página de teste para apágina de produção continuou dando o mesmo erro. :/